# Particles not exchanging velocity correctly

Tags: python

I want to create a little particle simulation with gravity, and so far i got the particles's velocity and bouncing of the wall correctly, but i have a problem with the particles colliding with each other and they do this.
[Particles grouping together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdlcA.png)

Here's the code

```
def resolve_collision(particle1, particle2):
  dst = distance(particle1.x, particle1.y, particle2.x, particle2.y)
  if dst < particle1.radius + particle2.radius:
    return particle2.velocity
  else:
    return particle1.velocity
```

All the particles have the same mass btw and so no need to calculate the entire one dimensional newtonian equation.

And here is the particle class

```
class Particle():
  def __init__(self, x, y, dx, dy,radius, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.velocity = [dx, dy]
    self.radius = radius
    self.color = color
  def update(self,particles):
    if self.y-self.radius<0 or self.y+self.radius>height:
      self.velocity[1] = -self.velocity[1]
    if self.x+self.radius>width or self.x-self.radius<0:
     self.velocity[0] = -self.velocity[0]
    self.x += self.velocity[0]
    self.y += self.velocity[1]
  for i in particles:
      if self != i:
        self.velocity = resolve_collision(self, i)
```

Comment: What are you doing with this returned velocity? We need to see more of the code

Comment: What is `particle.velocity`? A 2D vector? And why exactly do you expect to resolve a collision by returning it?

Comment: Are they getting stuck inside each other radii and bouncing around inside?

Comment: Probably what's going on is that you're sequentially applying this to pairs of particles.  If particle 1 and 2 collide particle 1 will take the velocity of particle 2.  Later in the loop you check 2 vs. 1 and decide that 2 takes the velocity of 1.  However, at this point the velocity of 1 is the same as 2.

Comment: I suspect your particles are overlapping and are repeatedly colliding at each iteration.

Comment: When they group together do they stick in one position or move around together?

Comment: Probably what's happening @KyleParsons i'll try to fix it

Comment: Also I'm not sure what kind of particle model would have the particles simply swap velocities when they collide? Maybe that works in 1 dimension...

Answer (score 0):

If after a successful collision, the next time you compare their positions, they have not moved outside the radii, then they will 'collide' again, but towards one an other.

Consider a simpler 1D toy model with just two particles. At some iteration, they are within 'radius' of one an other, their velocities exchange. If at the next iteration they have not moved outside the 'radius', then they 'collide' again and their velocities will exchange again sending them back towards each other - hence the 'grouping' you're seeing.

When you detect a collision, you need to determine whether the particles are moving toward one an other or away from one an other to determine whether its a real collision or not.

You should read this Wiki article on [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solutions

- First
- Second

##### First Solution

I see you defined your class particle's location and movement, attribute and method respectively, by hand, therefore, redesigning it to use a discrete form of location will solve your problem. You can do it using a Numpy grid of zeros *e.g.* `np.zeros([28,28])`, assigning particle location based on Numpy indexes on that grid and its confirmed position based on a value of integers ranging 0 to 1.

The following code illustrates the concept.

```py
import numpy as np


def DisplayImage(image):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.gray()
    plt.imshow(image)
    return plt.show()


grid = np.zeros([28, 28])
grid[1, 1] = 1
grid[10, 4] = 1
DisplayImage(grid)
```

Adding: You could also make it move "float" like by defining those particles locations based on Numpy matrices, which would make the coding a bit more cumbersome, but not that hard as there are innumerable ways of doing it.

Also, the resulting code could be reused by you in all your 2D models.

##### Second Solution

If your intent is to keep the current design. Writing a `switch`<sup>*1*</sup> class will ease the process of solving positional conflicts and if statements *i.e.*

```py
class Switcher(object):
    def indirect(self, i):
        method_name = "number_" + str(i)
        method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: "Invalid")
        return method()

    def number_0(self):
        return "zero"

    def number_1(self):
        return "one"

    def number_2(self):
        return "two"
```

**1**:[Two Simple Ways to Implement Switchers in Python](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-switch-case/)